# Is there a way to assert on partial text matching?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium OpenQA in C# and trying to write an assert that will compare two strings and assert True if some of the text in the first string matches the partial text in the second string.

```
string ActualValue = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.Toastify__toast.Toastify__toast--error")).Text;

Assert.IsTrue(ActualValue.Contains("There was an error validating your API key. Please contact Support and provide us with your public facing IP address:"));
```

My 'ActualValue' string is picking up this text string and I need to match it to the string above (minus the IP address):
"There was an error validating your API key. Please contact Support and provide us with your public facing IP address:22.12.23.14"

This test fails to evaluate to True.

```
string ActualValue = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.Toastify__toast.Toastify__toast--error")).Text;

Assert.IsTrue(ActualValue.Contains("There was an error validating your API key. Please contact Support and provide us with your public facing IP address:"));
```

Expected results - since the first string is contained in the second string, I expect the assert.is true == true
Actual results -I get the message that the assert failed 'Message:   Expected: True
  But was:  False'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great learning opportunity to write better asserts that will help debug this and other issues. Instead of writing an assert that evaluates to `true`/`false`, write one that will give you more information. For example, when your assert fails you get the message

```
Expected: true
But was:  false
```

Not terribly helpful, right? Instead use `StringAssert.Contains()` like

```
string expected = "There was an error validating your API key. Please contact Support and provide us with your public facing IP address:";
string actual = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#item")).Text;
StringAssert.Contains(expected, actual, "Verify error message.");
```

Now when your assert fails, you get the information below.

```
"Verify error message."
    Expected: String containing "There was an error validating your API key. Please contact Support and provide us with your public facing IP address:"
    But was: "There was an error validating your API key. Please contact Support and provide us with your public facing IP address:22.12.23.14"
```

Now if your strings are different, you can compare the two and see where the issue is. If you've already compared the actual and expected strings and don't see any difference, you probably need to look at them as ASCII values to find the non-printable character.

Also... always, always, always write an assert comment. It's the third string in an assert after expected and actual, e.g.

```
StringAssert.Contains(expected, actual, "Verify error message.");
```

It serves as a label for the failure and will help you determine which assert actually failed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added the stringAssert and a wait condition and now it finds the string consistently, turned out it was sometimes not able to identify the toast because of the speed it was running the test, so adding a wait condition made sure the element was visible and wouldn't give me a null string!

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine:

Target html for selenium "default.html"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="item">There was an error validating your API key. Please contact Support and provide us with your public facing IP address: 102.2.10.11</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Url = "file:///C:/Users/Espen/source/repos/Test/default.html"; // path to website under test
var str = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#item")).Text;
Assert.IsTrue(str.Contains("There was an error validating your API key. Please contact Support and provide us with your public facing IP address:"));
```

I am thinking either your text has a typo on either side of the test, or your selector hits one or multiple targets. I would consider using ids to select instead of class selectors when targeting specific elements.

Comment: thanks for the help, it turns out it was a wait condition I needed because sometimes the string would be null, other times it ran and would pass if it was able to find the element in time.